# several start-up scripts?

Tags: grub2, kubuntu, startup

I want kubuntu to ask me at start up - which of the profile I want to use. There should be a default answer which should run automatically in 3 seconds. Much as if were Grub asking You which operational system You would like to start.

The rational to have several start-up options: normally I have a lot of things starting by default: krusader, firefox, konsole, emacs... So the full loading takes about 1 minute. But sometimes - I'm on the run, and need just to do some single thing - so I'll need only, say krusader. I'd've made several start-up scripts... So I'm  wondering - is it possible to choose between them at start up?

Perhaps that could be done with Grub...

**Edit**:

Grub didn't asked me about the start up profile at all - that is not even "Normal mode" or "Recovery mode". I made him do it with Grub Editor (the package is called `kcm-grub2`):

```
sudo sed -i '$ a\deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:ksmanis/xUbuntu_11.10/ /' /etc/apt/sources.list
wget -q http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:ksmanis/xUbuntu_11.10/Release.key -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kcm-grub2
```

After the installation and restart, in `System settings` -> `Startup and Shutdown` new item has appeared: `Grub2 Bootloader`. In there - I checked "Automatically choose the default boot entry in 3 seconds".

After that, following the [lumbric](https://askubuntu.com/users/27088/lumbric) solution I've copied the `gnu-linux` `menuentry` record to the end of the `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`, and add a "productivity-profile" there. Here's the text of the modified `40_custom`:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry 'Full' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
        recordfail
        set gfxpayload=$linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 392f79ba-0f1f-422f-ac76-11860e0f4869
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-16-generic root=UUID=392f79ba-0f1f-422f-ac76-11860e0f4869 ro   quiet splash vt.handoff=7 productivity-profile=1
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-16-generic
}
menuentry 'Public' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
        recordfail
        set gfxpayload=$linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 392f79ba-0f1f-422f-ac76-11860e0f4869
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-16-generic root=UUID=392f79ba-0f1f-422f-ac76-11860e0f4869 ro   quiet splash vt.handoff=7 productivity-profile=2
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-16-generic
}
menuentry 'Fastest' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
        recordfail
        set gfxpayload=$linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 392f79ba-0f1f-422f-ac76-11860e0f4869
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-16-generic root=UUID=392f79ba-0f1f-422f-ac76-11860e0f4869 ro   quiet splash vt.handoff=7 productivity-profile=3
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-16-generic
}
```

`productivity-profile` is picked up by the Start-up bash script.

That's it. Now I have 5 start-up profiles: Clean, Recovery, Full, Public, Fastest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of [@Lekensteyn](https://askubuntu.com/users/6969/lekensteyn), I made a version where you can select the profile in GRUB. The creation of the custom menu can be still improved probably.

### Step 1: create custom GRUB menu

You need to create GRUB menu entries with an additional parameter. You can follow [this instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Custom_Menu_Entries). So copy your default entry from `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` (the lines with `menuentry ... { ... }`) to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`.

Then edit (the copied entry in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`) the line where it says `linux /boot...` and add at the and of a line seperated with a space:

```
productivity-profile=1
```

You can also edit the name of the menu entry, so change the part `menuentry 'Ubuntu, with...` to something like `menuentry 'Ubuntu (Profile 1), with...`.

Add such a menu entry for each of your profiles (with a unique number each).

You can remove the execute permissions from the other files in `/etc/grub.d/` in order to remove these menu entries. Don't forget to run `sudo update-grub` afterwards.

Note that after a kernel update, you'd have to change your grub menu manually if you follow this instructions! (You can improve this answer and describe how to edit the scripts in `/etc/grub.d/` accordingly.´)

### Step 2: check if Step 1 was successful

Reboot and select one of the profiles. Then run in a terminal:

```
cat /proc/cmdline
```

You should get something like:

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.... root=...  productivity-profile=2
```

...where the number at the end of the line has to be the chosen profile.

### Step 3: Adopt script to your needs and run it on start up

Then use this script to run your start up scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash    

profile=$(cat /proc/cmdline |sed 's/.*productivity-profile=\([0-9]\).*/\1/g')

echo Running profile $profile ...

case $profile in
   1)
      # Run script for profile 1
      ./script-profile1.sh
      ;;
   2)
      # Run script for profile 1
      ./script-profile2.sh
      ;;
   3)
      # Run script for profile 1
      ./script-profile3.sh
      ;;
   *)
      echo Error
      ;;
esac
```

Comment: Suggestions: use `grep -Po 'productivity-profile=\K[0-9]' /proc/cmdline` (I learned this at [unix.se](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13472/8250)). To avoid having manually to enter the kernel version, see [this answer to add extra boot entries for switching nvidia drivers](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24671/8250)

Comment: Wow, great! I was searching often how to do this with `grep`, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can run the following script on start up:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Press a key...'
echo '[1] Full profile (default)'
echo '[2] whatever 2'
echo '[3] another one'

read -t 3 -n 1 -p "Choose profile: " profile

echo

case $profile in
   1)
      # Run script for profile 1
      ./script-profile1.sh
      ;;
   2)
      # Run script for profile 1
      ./script-profile2.sh
      ;;
   3)
      # Run script for profile 1
      ./script-profile3.sh
      ;;
   *)
      echo Invalid choice
      ;;
esac
```

If you want, you can include a loop, so that it asks you again in case of an invalid choice or you can program it entirely in your favourite programming language.

But I agree, it would be more nice to choose the profile in the beginning of the boot process. You could power on the computer, choose the profile and then return when everything is started. But I don't know how to use parameters from GRUB.

Comment: `/proc/cmdline` contains the boot options.

Comment: That is very nice. I'm gining it a try!

Comment: Nope - it doesn't work: it doesn't ask me. It just do the default thing. I tried to `konsole -e "theScript.bash"` - then I can choose the option - but after loading - everything closing again. I tried to append ampersand - no help.

Comment: I also tried to do in with `kdialog` - but it doesn't have a "use the default after 3 seconds" options.

Comment: @Lekensteyn ah great! Do think it matters if one adds custom (meaningless) parameters in Grub? One could easily use the grub menu for choosing such profile options.

Comment: @Adobe What happens if you first run konsole and then enter there `./theScript.bash`?

Comment: @lumbric Nope, it does not matter. Just do not use exotic characters as other programs parses the cmdline as well. Options are space-separated (common practise), so you can use sth like `productivity-profile=web`

Comment: @Lekensteyn Yeah, great! I realized the GRUB version of the task with your help. Great thing, this could be adopted to a lot of usefull start up tasks...